# Linecast stop just before Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to do a Linecast, but it is too accurate so it isn't working the way I want.

I can't seem to figure out how to do a line cast from point `A` and stopping `0.001f` away from point `B` (Point `A` meaning `camera.transform.position` and Point `B` meaning `handle` in the snippet).

```
foreach(Vector3 handle in handles){
    if(!Physics.Linecast(camera.transform.position, handle)){
        Handles.FreeMoveHandle(handle, Quaternion.identity, 0.001f, Vector3.zero, Handles.DotCap);
    }
}
```

So, from the camera to the point, how can I get the `Linecast` to stop before the point?

## Edit

### Front View

In the front view not all the Handles show:

[image: Front]

### Back View

In the back view almost all the handles are there:

[image: Back]

## Full Code

**CreatureCreatorEditor.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Creature;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Creator))]
public class CreatureCreatorEditor : Editor {
    
    HashSet<Vector3> handles = new HashSet<Vector3>();

    void OnEnable(){
        Creator t = (Creator)target;
        Mesh mesh = t.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        if (mesh != null) {
            Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
            Vector3 lp = t.transform.position;
            foreach (Vector3 v in vertices) {
                Vector3 p = (lp - v);
                handles.Add(new Vector3 (p.x, -p.z, p.y));
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnSceneGUI(){
        Handles.color = Color.red;
        Camera camera = Camera.current;
        foreach(Vector3 handle in handles){
            Vector3 point = camera.WorldToViewportPoint(handle);
            if(point.x > 0 && point.x < 1 && point.y > 0 && point.y < 1){
//              float dist = Vector3.Distance(camera.transform.position, handle);
//              Vector3 fwd = camera.transform.TransformDirection(handle);
                Vector3 newBPos = new Vector3(handle.x - 0.001f, handle.y - 0.001f, handle.z - 0.001f);
                if(!Physics.Linecast(camera.transform.position, newBPos)){
                    Handles.FreeMoveHandle(handle, Quaternion.identity, 0.001f, Vector3.zero, Handles.DotCap);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI(){

    }
}
```

**Creator.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

namespace Creature{
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]
    public class Creator : MonoBehaviour {

    }
}
```

Comment: camera.transform.position is the point A and handle is the point B?

Comment: Do you want this to apply to all axis? a,y,z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like how this works, i just need to get the Y axis to work properly.

```
public void OnSceneGUI(){
    Camera camera = Camera.current;
    Handles.color = Color.red;
    Vector3 mp = Event.current.mousePosition;
    Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(mp);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
        Vector3 pos = hit.point;
        foreach(Vector3 handle in handles){
            if(Vector3.Distance(handle, pos) <= 0.05f){
                Handles.FreeMoveHandle(handle, Quaternion.identity, 0.001f, Vector3.zero, Handles.DotCap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an offset. You should subtract 0.001f from the B position.

This will do it to x,y,z position.

```
const float newPosOffset = 0.001f;

    foreach(Vector3 handle in handles){
    Vector3 newBPos = new Vector3(handle.x-newPosOffset ,handle.y-newPosOffset ,handle.z-newPosOffset );
        if(!Physics.Linecast(camera.transform.position, newBPos)){
            Handles.FreeMoveHandle(handle, Quaternion.identity, 0.001f, Vector3.zero, Handles.DotCap);
        }
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'll add pictures in a moment

Comment: Okay I have added images please take a look

Comment: So you want all the handles to show just like in back view?

Comment: yes, I wan't it to work no matter what view/angle I am looking at the model.

Comment: I want to check if my code makes a difference. If you replace my code with your code, does it show everything just like the back view or not. Does my code make a difference? Also what makes you think that stopping before 0.001f will make it work?

Comment: And when you change your code to your code, does the Back View remain good or not. I want to know where I have to change the code.

Comment: I think the problem is the direction the camera is facing. Do you mind posting the whole code(just the class that makes that handle to show). I will create a replica scene and fix from there. Also, tell me which code is connected to class or the game object you have in your scene.

Comment: is any of the codes suppose to attach to a  game object?

Comment: attach **Creator.cs** to the gameobject, it needs a `mesh collider` and a `mesh filter`, it will add them if you don't already have them

Comment: Ok. I will let you know when its fixed

Comment: Just woke up and tried your first code with a Capsule as the GameObject/model but it aren't working.  It is suppose to hose just the points in back view correct? Am I missing anything?